# Fault-Tolerant Distributed Work Sharing

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems

I have a network of 1,000 computers that are sharing processing jobs. There are a few constraints:

1. Each computer has a maximum ratio of jobs it can perform

   - Can be higher than an equal share
2. Computers are not obligated to do work
3. Not all of these computers will be online at any given time
4. Jobs should be processed quickly
5. Jobs do not have to be processed sequentially
6. Some duplicated work is OK

   - all computers trying to do the same job would cause unacceptable waste and congestion

So far, the best idea I can come up with is a system where the computers mark themselves as available for work and a round-robin queue is built where each job has N computers that may perform the work. The first computer to submit the work "wins" it. Once the queue is emptied, it is re-built again based on the computers available.

This makes it so even if a computer is assigned jobs but does not submit work the job does not get stuck - because others will pick it up. Computers with a higher allowable ratio would be given multiple entries in the queue.

The "ratio" is like a weighted round-robin, where Computer A is allowed to do 10% of the jobs, Computer B is allowed to do 5% of the jobs, and so on.

The desired output is a method to:

- complete the work quickly
- with minimal coordination between the computers
- as little duplicated work as possible
- without letting computers do more work than their max ratio

Is there a better approach that has already been created and proven?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem statement.  If you want an algorithm, what is the input ot the algorithm, and what is the output from the algorithm?  What is meant by "ratio of jobs".  What is it meant to share processing jobs?  What exactly is your question?  How will you evaluate candidate answers?  "better" by what metric/criteria?  This sounds a bit vague/imprecise to me.

Comment: I think what you have designed is a typical way to do this. There is no amazing theoretical algorithm - *all distributed systems problems suck*.